# Displaying another line after pressing <ENTER>?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a project and have to use the scanner for user input.

If given the text file "names.txt" and each file was like such

```
Mike John
Johnny Apple
Isaac Nad
Zoe Za
```

I want it to display the first line which is `Mike John` in the terminal, then once I hit the ENTER key it prints `Johnny Apple`.

Does anyone know how to do this? I've been struggling.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class enter {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("name.txt"));
    
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                }
    
                scanner.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }
    
    }
```

See the above, it just displays all of them at the same time. This is also not a JAVAFX program, its solely terminal based

Comment: Write separate methods.  One method to read your name file into a String array.  One method to write the contents of the String array, asking for user input after each line.

Answer (score 2):

You need two Scanners:

```
Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("name.txt"));

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.print(scanner.nextLine());
    keybd.nextLine(); // wait for enter to be pressed
}

keybd.close();
scanner.close();
```